# Отслеживание динамических путей во vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

У меня на сайте есть карточки товаров с расположенными под ними кнопками `купить`.
когда я нажимаю на кнопку меня перебрасывает на страницу с товаром. Примерно `example.com/product`
Задается вопрос как во vue сделать динамический роутинг с передачей в него параметров? Например передавать его описание, ценуи картинку. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: а что по этому поводу говорит официальный сайт https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html?

Comment: Прочитал, но так и не понял как передавать в параметрах допустим названия, цену товара и тд.

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#%D0%B1%D1%83n%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 2):

При кликаем на продукте

```
<vCatalogItem
                    :index="i"
                    :key="product.article"
                    :observer="observer"
                    :product_data="product"
                    @addToCart="addToCart"
                    @productClick="productClick"
                    v-for="(product, i) in filteredProducts"
            />
```

Передаем данные в компонент, например article

```
productClick(article) {
                this.$router.push({name: 'product', query: {'product': article}})
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Прямая передача данных через router-view

```
<router-view :item="item" :settings="settings"></router-view>
```